# Connect to MQ inside a Scrapy spider or how to create ClientCreator inside Scrapy spider

Tags: scrapy, mq

I want to solve this issue: connect to MQ inside a spider.

Im trying to call `ClientCreator`, but i dont know where to get "reactor" variable inside a CrawlSpider...

```
d = ClientCreator(reactor, AMQClient, delegate=delegate, vhost='/', spec=spec).connectTCP('localhost', 5672)
d.addCallback(self.gotConnection, 'guest', 'guest')
```

Why i am connecting to MQ inside a spider and dont use `Pipeline`? I have a loop running spider that reads some jobs from MQ. Pipelines provides a storage, but i need to read and proccess MQ jobs. I cant read jobs and that run spider, cause i need to proccess mq jobs while spider is already logged in on website.

Does somebody have any suggessions how to connect to MQ inside a spider not to store parsed items but to read jobs?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I have not tried this at home.

I think your best bet is to just do:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

and then use that `reactor` with the `ClientCreator`.

If you take a look at the [example of running a spider from a script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) from the official documentation page you will see that its just the same `reactor` being used.

Comment: Nothing happend... i`m need to use it in __init__ method inside a Scrapy CrawlSpider. I can`t run spider from a script for each MQ message due to business logic of my app.